# What is the difference between recursion and tail-recursion?

Tags: loops, recursion, scheme, racket

I am new to the scheme language and one of the things the professor talked about was tail recursion. I didn't quite get it. Can someone please explain to me in detail what is meant by tail recursion and how it differs from normal recursion?

Also, does anyone have any idea on how For-loop and Which-Loop were implemented in languages like C++, Java etc. This part is just for curiosity purposes.

Thanks